# C#: Have a "Optional" Parameter that by default uses the value of a required parameter

Tags: c#, nullable

How can i implement a "optional" parameter to a function such that when `endMarker` is not given, i will use the value from a required parameter `startMarker`? i currently use a nullable type and check if `endMarker` is null i set it to `startMarker`

```
protected void wrapText(string startMarker, string? endMarker = null) { 
    if (endMarker == null)
        endMarker = startMarker; 
}
```

but the problem now is i get an error saying it cannot cast `string?` into `string`

```
(string)endMarker
```

how can i cast `endMarker` to a `string` so i can use it? or is there a better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will work:

```
protected void wrapText(string startMarker, string endMarker = null) { 
    if (endMarker == null)
        endMarker = startMarker; 
}
```

In other words: remove the question mark from the `string?`. `System.String` is a reference type and can already be `null`. The `Nullable<T>` structure can only be used on value types.

Comment: It's important to note that this is only possible in C# 4 and onwards.

Comment: just want to add, the code can be shorten to `endMarker = endMarker ?? startMarker`

Comment: @JiewMeng And as of C# 8.0, that can even further be shortened to `endMarker ??= startMarker`

Answer (score 4):

You need to overload the method to have a call without the "optional" parameter.  Then in this method you just call the normal method passing in the same parameter twice:

```
protected void wrapText(String startMarker, String endMarker) 
{  
    // do stuff 
} 


protected void wrapText(String startMarker) 
{  
    wrapText(startMarker, startMarker);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
protected void wrapText(string startMarker, string? endMarker = null) { 
    if (endMarker == null)
    {
        endMarker = "foo";
        endMarker = startMarker;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: This just sets `endMarker` to be `startMarker` whatever happens.

Comment: better now, or should i just quit while i'm behind?

Comment: You can't have a `Nullable<string>` (or `string?` which is the same) - a string is already nullable (it's a reference type)